# Android parsing HTML with letter 'ñ'

Tags: android, html, parsing, ascii

In my application I read some HTML from an URL and show the content to the user.

Everything works fine but there's an issue when the letter 'ñ' appears.

What I do:

```
SingleEvent.Competition = helper.substring(0, helper.indexOf(")"));
```

After doing this I get,

```
SingleEvent.Competition = "GRAN PREMIO RED BULL DE ESPAÃA"
```

And the expected result is:

```
SingleEvent.Competition = "GRAN PREMIO RED BULL DE ESPAÑA"
```

Any idea about how to correct this?

Comment: Where? I'm doing this in Java

Comment: I'm quite sure the problem is not the substring method. It may be a good idea to examine the HTML of your URL, and the charset header.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"/>  . The website shows the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = URLDecoder.decode(myString, "UTF-8");
```

so, in your case:

```
SingleEvent.Competition = URLDecoder.decode("GRAN PREMIO RED BULL DE ESPAÃA", "UTF-8");
```